# Setting up WAMP to run on a LAN

Tags: wamp, lan

I've installed WAMP on a Windows 7 PC, and it is running fine locally, as localhost.

I want PCs on the LAN to be able to view the local server.  When they load my PC's IP address in their browser, they receive a "You don't have permission to access / on this server" error.

I followed [this guide](http://www.logicspot.com/posts/viewing-a-locally-hosted-website-with-your-smartphone/), but the issue remains.  To recap:

- I've added an inbound exception to Windows Firewall for port 80 for Private and Domain connections.
- I've edited Apache's httpd.conf to include:

> Listen 80
>
> Listen 192.168.0.5:80
>
> < Directory "c:/wamp/www/wordpress/" >  
>    allow from all 
>   <
>   /Directory >

- I've edited httpd-vhosts.conf to include:

> < VirtualHost 192.168.0.5:80 >
>    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/wordpress"
>   
>  < /VirtualHost >

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my local Wordpress, the Wordpress address and Site address were both using localhost.

I changed this to the IP address, and the problem is resolved.

Answer (score 2):

The top-level folder must have the right permissions set (in your case `c:/wamp/www/`).  Try to change

```
< Directory "c:/wamp/www/wordpress/" > allow from all < /Directory >
```

with

```
< Directory "c:/wamp/www/" > allow from all < /Directory >
```

Hope it helps.